# Summing across arrays during aggregation pipeline

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a model with a few arrays of the same fixed size and I've been trying to work out whether I can sum across the array indices using the aggregation pipeline, but have been having a difficult time finding anything helpful.

For example:

```
{  
    label: "label1",

    A: [0, 0, 0],   
    B: [1, 1, 1],  
    C: [0, 0, 1],

    etc: ... ,
}
```

Would need to produce the following summed array during a projection, or another similar array when grouping on the label key further down the pipeline:

```
{  
    Z: [1, 1, 2]  
}
```

Using Mongo 3.2 I can unwind an array and maintain its indices, but I'm still not sure how to rebuild an array using those indices and values.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, it would mean a lot. Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: what max size can an array have?

Answer (score 1):

One could use $slice to slice array if it is a small size (3x3 means 9 operations), but unwinding it will generate 27 documents for 3x3 arrays so connecting them back is a kind of pain.

***or you could use simpler solution using forEach***

```
var arraySize=3;
var a=[];
db.david.find({label:"label2"}).forEach(function(myDoc) {     
      for(var i=0;i<arraySize;i++){ 
          a[i]=myDoc.A[i]+myDoc.B[i]+myDoc.C[i];
      }
      })
 printjson( a )
```

---

***edit***

I am still not sure how to bite this in more dynamic way - but this is a kind of proposal for 3 arrays of 3 elements each.

```
var arraySumprojection = {
            $project : {
                col1 : {
                    $let : {
                        vars : {
                            a : {
                                "$arrayElemAt" : ["$A", 0]
                            },
                            b : {
                                "$arrayElemAt" : ["$B", 0]
                            },
                            c : {
                                "$arrayElemAt" : ["$C", 0]
                            },

                        },
                        in : {
                            $add : ["$$a", "$$b","$$c"]
                        }
                    }
                },

                col2 : {
                    $let : {
                        vars : {
                            a : {
                                "$arrayElemAt" : ["$A", 1]
                            },
                            b : {
                                "$arrayElemAt" : ["$B", 1]
                            },
                            c : {
                                "$arrayElemAt" : ["$C", 1]
                            },

                        },
                        in : {
                            $add : ["$$a", "$$b","$$c"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                col3 : {
                    $let : {
                        vars : {
                            a : {
                                "$arrayElemAt" : ["$A", 2]
                            },
                            b : {
                                "$arrayElemAt" : ["$B", 2]
                            },
                            c : {
                                "$arrayElemAt" : ["$C", 2]
                            },

                        },
                        in : {
                            $add : ["$$a", "$$b","$$c"]
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight! If my understanding is correct, the forEach(...) method is only applied to the cursor after the aggregation pipeline, so I couldn't use that method if summing across the arrays was an intermediate step. I'll play around with it and see if I make any progress.

Comment: @DavidB what is the max array size?

Comment: @DavidB 28*28? that could be complex

Comment: Each document has anywhere from 1 to about 15 of these 28-item arrays, and I'm trying to work out a good way to produce results summing across some number of them while maintaining the indices. I might opt to refactor the data with explicit keys for each index and combine them that way during the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: @DavidB - that is a kinda nice challenge - please see my update -  I wish that this will direct you to get solution!

Comment: I like the approach you added to your post. Thanks for all your help!